# scrollHeight property in FireFox

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a function to detect whether text inside of a DIV element would overflow. In this regard I have a function working in both Chrome and IE that compares the element's scrollHeight to the clientHeight attributes.

However in FireFox both attributes (as well as offsetHeight) always report the same number which happens to be the height of the div element.

I do get accurate results from the scrollHeight property if I add 'overflow:auto' to the div style. But displaying the scrollbar isn't an acceptable solution for the project I'm working on.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's documented behaviour:

> When an element's content does not
>   generate a vertical scrollbar, then
>   its scrollHeight property is equal to
>   its clientHeight property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollHeight

---

I know that it isn't clean, but could you do something like this?

```
e.style.overflow = "scroll";
var scrollHeight = e.scrollHeight;
e.style.overflow = "hidden";
```

The user can't see that because the page only gets redrawn when no javascript is currently running.

Comment: Even jQuery has to perform the swapping out trick of CSS fields to calculate dimensions correctly.  Note that in general you should save the value first, then restore it, rather than assuming it is hidden.

Comment: I thought I read the spec but obviously not close enough if I missed that. Thank's for pointing it out for me. BTW, what function in jQuery does this?

Comment: sorry to bring up old thread

I'm here with the same problem, clientHeight and scrollHeight is giving me equal value even if the div has scrollbar

My browser is Firefox 6.0, is this a known bug?

Comment: This no longer happens ever since FireFox version 21.

Answer (score 3):

Kartikaya Gupta explains Firefox's behavior in [a blog post on the scrollWidth/scrollHeight properties](https://staktrace.com/spout/entry.php?id=751).

The recommendation to detect if an element would overflow is to make it scrollable and set `scrollLeft`/`scrollTop` to 1 temporarily. When at least `scrollWidth` or `scrollHeight` keeps its value then the element would overflow.
In order to prevent the check being visible to the user, you might want to perform the check in a cloned element that is placed in the negative top or left of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

In the actual Firefox version this is not a problem anymore because the scrollHeight property works even without the overflow="scroll" trick pointed here. But in some old versions it still happens so...

thank you very much @thejh, your hint was very useful for me!

Comment: Are you sure? I have FF version 46 (current stable release) and it doesn't work. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/gjrowe/X63KR/