# .body.scrollHeight doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript

`.body.scrollHeight` does not work in Firefox.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/gjrowe/X63KR/

What is the correct syntax to use instead?

Comment: These pages seems to contain info about the issue; http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?73161-.scrollHeight-in-firefox, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollHeight, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369990/scrollheight-property-in-firefox

Comment: I got 0 on the alert but after adding a bunch of `<br />` it seems to work

Comment: @Allendar Other people asking the same with no answer

Comment: @RodrigoAssis Ok... I added some `<br>` and it seems to increase from 0 but it is not the height of the scrollable area... it seems to be the height of the content.

Comment: Sorry G-J. Try to see this jQuery hack; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471286/window-scrollfunction-not-working-on-firefox. You could backtrace the solution to the jQuery source and clone the functionality of the given hack/answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This question has the same root problem as the thread at... [Dynamically define iframe height based on window size (NOT CONTENT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15934161/dynamically-define-iframe-height-based-on-window-size-not-content/15935330#15935330)

Understanding the issue at that thread will give the solution to this.

Basically, instead of using `.body.scrollHeight`, add this code...

```
function getDocHeight() {
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
}
```

The answer was obtained from: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/get-document-height-cross-browser/

Comment: Has this code stopped working in the past 3 years since the answer was given? I just tested it in Firefox and found that it yields the same value as just using document.body.scrollHeight.

Comment: @BrandonElliott I'll test it and get back to you, but the issue is caused by body.scrollHeight not being reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) (WebDriverObject);
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight || document.documentElement.scrollHeight)", "");
```