# Script works fine in any WebKit based browser but doesn't in Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, firefox

I have a script in (using wordpress) header.php which looks like this:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  fixedMenu.init("header-container", 0);
  fixedMenu.init("event-type-wrapper", 20);
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function(fid){
    fixedMenu.top("header-container");
    fixedMenu.top("event-type-wrapper");
  });
  var sessionvar = "<?php echo $_SESSION['lang'] ?>";
});
```

after this script I include a longer one script with the script scr="" tag.

In that script I have

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    todays = document.getElementById("todays-events");
    upcomming = document.getElementById("upcomming-events");
    past = document.getElementById("past-events");
    texter = document.getElementById("event-type");

    changeMessage();
});
```

It works fine in any webkit browser, the code is launched, but firefox doesn't load second event listener (I do not know how to debug if it loads or not, but I don't see result in the webpage).

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

If there is need, here is the full source for the script embedded through script src=

```
var todays;
var upcomming;
var past;
var texter;

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    todays = document.getElementById("todays-events");
    upcomming = document.getElementById("upcomming-events");
    past = document.getElementById("past-events");
    texter = document.getElementById("event-type");

    changeMessage();
});

window.onscroll = function(){
  changeMessage();
}

function isElementInViewport (el) {
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

  return (
    rect.top >= 0 &&
    rect.left >= 0 &&
    rect.bottom <= document.body.scrollHeight &&
    rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
  );
}

function changeMessage(){
  if(texter && todays && isElementInViewport(todays)){
    texter.textContent = returnString("Šiandien", "Today", "Сегодня");
  }
  else {
    if(texter && upcomming && isElementInViewport(upcomming)){
        texter.textContent = returnString("Artėjantys","Upcomming","Предстоящие");
    }
    else{
        if(texter && past && isElementInViewport(past)){
            texter.textContent = returnString("Praėję", "Past", "Прошлое");
        }
    }
  }
}

function returnString(lt, en, ru){
  if (!(typeof sessionvar === 'undefined')) {
    if(sessionvar == 'en_EN'){
        return en;
    }
    else if(sessionvar == 'ru_RU'){
        return ru;
    }
  }
  return lt;
}
```

Comment: that's why there is [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com)

Comment: look there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code

Comment: @Kaiido I understand the debugger with breakpoints, but I don't understand how to watch events in that debugger.

Comment: Well I would use firebug and `console.log(event)` in the event function, then I would move my console.log until I find where it breaks and why. Don't you have any error thrown?

Comment: I ended up logging to console the change message and and those ifs inside and they all gave me false. The problem was that firefox reports document.body.scrollHeight as 0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that firefox reports

```
document.body.scrollHeight
```

as 0, because of that every `if` inside `changeMessage()` failed by returning false.

The solution was found in SO: [.body.scrollHeight doesn't work in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932650/body-scrollheight-doesnt-work-in-firefox)

quote:

```
function getDocHeight() {
  var D = document;
  return Math.max(
    Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
    Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
    Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what is not working is the code inside *changeMessage* function, because Firefox doesn't understand *element.innerText*, and you have to change to *element.textContent*

Comment: you are right about that I set the message with `*.inner*`, just not with `innerText`, but with `innerHTML`, if I do in firefox console `element.innerHTML = "test"` then it works without problems. Tried `textContent` - didn't work.

Comment: what happens when you put the inline script like this:

  var sessionvar = "<?php echo $_SESSION['lang'] ?>";
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  fixedMenu.init("header-container", 0);
  fixedMenu.init("event-type-wrapper", 20);
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function(fid){
    fixedMenu.top("header-container");
    fixedMenu.top("event-type-wrapper");
  });
});